# Android - adjusting triggers for remote server from app

Tags: android, sql-server, triggers, websocket, android-activity

I am developing an app as part of my final year project.  Server part, PHP ,is already complete for sending accepting requests from the android application, I am using websocket technology.

For the android application I want to create an android activity, for adjusting with android trigger buttons (ON/OFF) some server functions.How requests will be send from the android app?

Comment: Umm, however you want them to be?  Generally you make an HTTP request to a predefined URL with 1 or more parameters.  Read some tutorials on webservices.

Comment: Yeah, I am really sorry I haven't specified more, I have already implemented HTTP requests on another android activity from having to recieve data from my server. Now I want to implement something similar, but for sending the requests to the server for adjusting the triggers